Is there a way to validate the web app authentication integation on SFMC?
https://${d(
        subDomain,
    )}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${d(
        clientId,
    )}&redirect_uri=${config.sfmc.AltusRedirectUri};

This is my url link to authenticate, but I am wondering if we can validate the url, currently if I put a not valid subDomain, clientId, and redireact URI, it will put it return This site can’t be reached and I am planning to handle that error on my react js frontend

Just try it, that is not really something you need much special knowledge in Marketing Cloud for.
Mess your subdomain up on purpose, send the API call. It returns StatusCode 596 unknown. React on that statuscode with an error and you're done.
Fix your subdomain, mess up clientId on purpose, send the API call. It returns StatusCode 401 Unauthorized. React on that statuscode with an error and you're done.
How to validate your redirect URI depends on what you put into it.
You can validate its existence by sending a HTTPGET. If you get a 404 it does not exist. React on that statuscode with an error and you're done.
Usually what you'd see is just a "statuscode is not 200" type of errorhandling.
